# Search and delete a directory which its name starts with tmp

Tags: python-3.x

Search for any folder named tmp* (for example tmp, tmp1, tmp_rr, and etc)

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import glob
import sys

dirpath = raw_input("Enter your PATH to search for 'tmp' files: ")

for files in os.listdir(dirpath):
    if files == "tmp*":
        os.rmdir(dirpath + "tmp*")
```

Answer (score 1):

You are matching the string with wildcards characters. In python you have a built-in method for matching the starting string called **str.startswith()**

Also you should remove the directory by using variable name **files** not by **"tmp*"**

```
for files in os.listdir(dirpath):
    if files.startswith("tmp"):
        os.rmdir(dirpath + files)
```

Comment: Thanks,
It works now.
How can I access to sub-directories and search and delete tmp* folders?

Comment: I didn't get your point. You can search for folders that starts with name by using `str.startswith()` and delete directory using `os.rmdir()`.

Comment: Thanks,
This scrips deletes all folders that their name start with tmp in a specified directory. My aim is to search all sub-directories either.

Answer (score 0):

Try [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html)

You can pass path pattern and also search recursively.